# Copying a partial row based on multiple column criteria and pasting to row based on same criteria

Tags: excel, vba

My destination workbook (wb1) is a table with a range of A1:Q740 and has a header row, the data workbook (wb2) that I want to copy from always has the same columns A:Q with the number of rows varying.

In both workbooks, the data in columns A:F for most, but not all rows is identical.  I would like to compare those columns in both worksheets, and if a given row in A:F matches the other workbook, copy the data from that row for columns G:Q from the data workbook to the row with matching data in the destination workbook.

My issue is most of the time the rows between the two workbooks don't line up. For example, in both workbooks cells A2:F2 match. However, the farther down the workbook you go the rows diverge. In the data workbook, cells A153:F153 are the same as the destination workbook cells A159:F159. So, in this example I would like my code to copy data from cells G2:Q2 and G153:Q153 and paste them to the destination workbook in cells G2:Q2 and G159:Q159, respectively.

I've got my workbooks, worksheets and ranges named, but I'm not sure how best to run the comparison or how to code the copy/paste destination correctly.

EDIT: Updated code as below, it works until row 34 and then breaks since the matching data is no longer in the same row number in each workbook.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergeWorksheets()

Dim wb1 As Workbook '2017 Tracking Report
Dim wb2 As Workbook 'Book# Drake Export from CSM
Dim Drake17 As Worksheet

Dim ImportDataFull As Range 'Full Range of Drake17 Export, less header row

Dim lastRow As Long 'Last Row of Drake17 Worksheet
Dim lastRow2 As Long 'Last Row of Drake Export

Dim ImportData As Range 'Drake Export Data
Dim DesImportData As Range 'Destination Range of Data for Compare

Dim DesImportRange As Range 'Destination for ImportRange

Set wb1 = Workbooks("2017 Tracking Report.xlsm")
Set wb2 = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count) 'Sets the most recently opened WB
Set Drake17 = wb1.Sheets("Drake17")

lastRow = Drake17.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set DesImportData = Drake17.Range("A1:F" & lastRow)
Set DesImportRange = Drake17.Range("G1:Q" & lastRow)

wb2.Activate

lastRow2 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set ImportDataFull = Range("A1:Q" & lastRow2) 'Full Data Export Less Header Row
Set ImportData = Range("A1:F" & lastRow2) 'Sets range of data to compare

Dim r As Range
Dim i As Integer

With Columns(6)
    .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyy"
    .Value = .Value
End With

With Columns(2)
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 2 To lastRow2

    With ImportDataFull
        Set r = Range("G" & i, "Q" & i)
            If ImportData.Cells(i, 1) = DesImportData.Cells(i, 1) And _
            ImportData.Cells(i, 2) = DesImportData.Cells(i, 2) And _
            ImportData.Cells(i, 3) = DesImportData.Cells(i, 3) And _
            ImportData.Cells(i, 4) = DesImportData.Cells(i, 4) And _
            ImportData.Cells(i, 5) = DesImportData.Cells(i, 5) And _
            ImportData.Cells(i, 6) = DesImportData.Cells(i, 6) Then
               r.Copy DesImportRange.Rows(i)
               r.EntireRow.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End If
    End With
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI - that final `With` statement currently is not doing anything. You must link the `Cells()` reference to that with the `.` before it, e.g. `If .Cells(i, 1) = ...` Otherwise, `Cells()` on the *ActiveSheet* will be used, which may not be what you're expecting.  Also same thing earlier, where you have naked `Range()` references.  Add the worksheet before that, i.e. `wb2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks. I've cleaned up the empty named ranges and tweaked the code a bit. I'm having success for the first 30 rows, then it breaks. See edit in post. I'm not sure how to handle comparing and copying data if the matching rows aren't in the same row number in each workbook.